# Selenium Java inheritance want to reuse xpath in anothor classs

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

`Selenium Java` inheritance want to reuse `xpath` in another class that registration forms has same button id like code below. I want reuse these three buttons in any class these buttons are

```
driver.findElementById("checkbox2").click();
driver.findElementById("checkbox1").click();
driver.findElementById("js-register").click();

public class Landindpage{ public void fill () {    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://qa-0.ls.vu/v2/landing-page/roche");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/div/div[2]/a[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[4]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Emmaname");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[4]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("Mohaname");
        /*for(int count=1; count < 10; i++){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[5]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("testing" + i + "@gmail.com");
            // Rest of the script
        }*/

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[5]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("0221-1234567");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[6]/div/select")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[6]/div/select/option[3]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[7]/div/select")).click();    
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[8]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/form/div[7]/div/select/option[4]")).click();
        driver.findElementById("checkbox2").click();
        driver.findElementById("checkbox1").click();
        driver.findElementById("js-register").click();
}

public  void googlefill (){ 

    driver.get("http://qa-0.ls.vu/v2/landing-page/google");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/p[2]/a/small")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Emmaname");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("Mohaname");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[4]/div/input")).sendKeys("aali3005@outlook.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[5]/div")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[5]/div/select/option[2]")).click();      
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[6]/div[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[6]/div[1]/select/option[4]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[6]/div[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[6]/div[2]/select/option[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[7]/div/input")).sendKeys("0221-1234567");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[8]/div")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[8]/div/select/option[5]")).click();
    /*driver.findElementById("checkbox2").click();
    driver.findElementById("checkbox1").click();
    driver.findElementById("js-register").click();*/
}
```

**there are two child classes of landing page**

```
package Database;


public class Rochee   extends Landindpage {

    public static void main(String[]args)  {
        Rochee obj=new Rochee();
        obj.fill();
    }
}

package Database;

public class google extends Landindpage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\workspace\\chromeDriver\\chromeDriver.exe");
        google bo1= new google();

        bo1.googlefill();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is adviced to avoid inheritance as a means of code-reuse, also read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/why-avoid-java-inheritance-extends

I suggest you have a look at the PageObject Model to remove code duplication from your tests. Read http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html and http://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/pageObjectModel.html

If you have code that is shared between different pages you could create a central class which you instantiate from within the page classes.

If you do not want to use page object model I would have a look in making a static class for your shared references.

```
public class Buttons {
    public static string first = "//path";
    public static string second = "//path";
}
```

now you can access them from anywhere by calling

```
Buttons.first;
Buttons.second;
```

Also read:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896111/sharing-constant-strings-in-java-across-many-classes
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646577/global-variables-in-java